# Vista style explorer/folder view

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, user-interface

I am trying to have a list of large (256x256) icons in a listview similar to vista explorer windows, but the winforms' listview control doesn't look like vista's listview.

Before I dig into WPF, can someone tell me if WPF listview can do this?

Basically I get this (solid blue selection):

[image]

instead of this (semi transparent blue selection):

[image]

Can I even achieve this using WinForms?

Btw I use Windows 7.

Comment: second link is generating a 404 not found error.

Comment: Converted the links into images.

Comment: Only one image, the second one is still broken

Comment: I uploaded the 2nd pic to a host. The original site is trying to be smart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about WPF, but in WinForms you must apply 'explorer' theme to your list view to achieve Explorer-like UI.

```
[DllImport("uxtheme.dll")]
public extern static int SetWindowTheme(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszSubAppName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszSubIdList);

SetWindowTheme(listView.Handle, "explorer", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this in WPF; you can use a Trigger as described in the MSDN article: [How to: Use Triggers to Style Selected Items in a ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743015.aspx).

[A complete sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771517.aspx) is also available for download.

I am uncertain if this is possible in WinForms.

**Update:** In response to the question in the comment below this is definitely possible.  Once again there is a sample online at MSDN titled [ListView That Sorts Data Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771680.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Rick. Do you also know if it's possible to have the exact explorer functionality (for viewing files) with custom filtering, etc?